# Elasticsearch check a key exists in an object

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-query

My partial mapping for one of the indexes:

```
{
  "title": { "type": "string"},
  "seasons": {
    "type": "object",
    "dynamic": true,
    "properties": {}
  }
}
```

Currently, I have 4 documents as follows:

Doc 1

```
{
  "title": "abc",
  "seasons": null
}
```

Doc 2

```
{
  "title": "xyz",
  "seasons": {
    "201809": 23,
    "201902": 45
  }
}
```

Doc 3

```
{
  "title": "xyz",
  "seasons": {
    "201811": 23,
    "201910": 23,
    "201809": 45,
    "201805": 35,
  }
}
```

Doc 4

```
{
  "title": "xyz",
  "seasons": {
    "201802": 23,
    "201902": 45
  }
}
```

`seasons` object will always be either `null` or will have `key=>val` pair.

I want to search all documents which have `season` field with key `201809` (here doc2 and doc3 qualify) in it and then do further work on the doc.

**REQUIREMENT - I need to run this search using groovy scripting only**. And in my groovy script I do have:

```
if (doc["seasons.201809"].value) {
   ....more processing after finding the document.....
}
```

But for this check I get `"TransportError(500, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'no_class_def_found_error: java/lang/Throwable')"`. 
I am sure this line is not the correct check

```
if (doc["seasons.201809"].value) {
```

Can anyone let me know how to solve this problem of checking a key existence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Groovy part, you can do the following:

```
// (1) More verbose approach
if (doc.containsKey('seasons') && doc.seasons.containsKey('201802')) {
    println "Key seasons.201802 exists!"
}
```

or:

```
// (2) Shorter version
if (doc?.seasons?.containsKey('201802')) {
    println "Key seasons.201802 exists!"
}
```

And here is some Groovy full sample:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

String json = '''{
  "title": "xyz",
  "seasons": {
    "201802": 23,
    "201902": 45
  }
}'''

Map doc = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

// (1) More verbose approach
if (doc.containsKey('seasons') && doc.seasons.containsKey('201802')) {
    println "(1) Key seasons.201802 exists!"
}

// (2) Shorter version
if (doc?.seasons?.containsKey('201802')) {
    println "(2) Key seasons.201802 exists!"
}
```

#### Output

```
(1) Key seasons.201802 exists!
(2) Key seasons.201802 exists!
```

Comment: I used the verbose version in my inline script and it worked, while shorter version did not. Thank you for helping me out solving the issue :)